# Swift read from JSON dictionary

Tags: json, swift

I am sending an `Alamofire` request and inside of my completion handler I have:

```
                if let jsonData = response.result.value {
                    
                    result = jsonData
                    guard let data = result.data(using: .utf8) else { return}
                    guard let dictionary = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] else {
                                        print("Could not cast JSON content as a Dictionary<String, Any>")
                                        return
                                    }
                            
                    print("dictionary: \(dictionary)")
                    if dictionary["status"] as! String == "false"{
                         //Do something
                                 }
                    }
            

                else{
                    result = "\(response.error)"
                    
                }
```

The result of printing `dictionary` is `["status":false, "value":A1]`. Ultimately I want to use `status` for my if statement. However I get a crash on the if statement line: `if dictionary["status"] as! String == "false"` of `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. I also tried changing the line to if `dictionary["status"] as! Bool == false` and I get the exact same error.

The json as returned from the request is:

```
{
    "value": "A1",
    "status": "false"
}
```

So my question is, what is the correct way to get the value for `status` out of `dictionary`?

Would something like this work?

```
struct jsonOut: Codable {
  let value: String
  let status: String
}

if let jsonData = response.result.value {

                    result = jsonData
                    guard let data = result.data(using: .utf8)
                    let status = try JSONDecoder().decode(jsonOut.self, from: data)

}
```

Comment: You need to show the initial JSON. Any reason why you don't use `Codable`?

Comment: Updated question with json and an attempt at `Codable`. I think I need a little bit of guidance there

Comment: Did you try the Codable code, it looks fine to me?

Comment: Then please remove the question or post your solution as an answer

Comment: Side note,  suspect you are using Alamofire, so use directly `.responseDecodabel(of:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the JSON has the format:

```
{
"value": "A1",
"status": "false"
}
```

The correct way is using `Codable` with the same format as the JSON:

```
struct jsonOut: Codable {
  let value: String
  let status: String
}

if let jsonData = response.result.value {

                    result = jsonData
                    guard let data = result.data(using: .utf8)
                    let statusData = try JSONDecoder().decode(jsonOut.self, from: data)

                    print("status: \(statusData.status)"
}
```